# Regex not working in HTML5 pattern

Tags: regex, html

So I have this regex intended to let pass all text but those that contain as initial chars the "34" sequence:

> ^(?!34)(?=([\w]+))

The regex is working fine for me in https://regex101.com/r/iN1yN3/2 , check the tests to see the intended behavior.

Any Idea why it isn't working in my form?

```html
<form>
    <input pattern="^(?!34)(?=([\w]+))" type="text">
    
        <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Note that your example on regex101 _[does not work](https://regex101.com/r/iN1yN3/2#javascript)_ if you change the flavour to JavaScript

Comment: @JamesThorpe It does work, check the matches section. Also all the test run. The problem is that it should match the whole string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern attribute has to match the entire string. Assertions check for a match, but do not count towards the total match length. Changing the second assertion to `\w+` will make the pattern match the entire string.

You can also skip the implied `^`, leaving you with just:

```
<input pattern="(?!34)\w+" type="text">
```

Comment: Fixed and improved. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: **The pattern attribute has to match the entire string.** This is the golden answer. Just commenting again as I had to think on it and just realize that the answer was written as the first sentence of the response. Thanks again @mcrumley